# Linux - Strip lines with zero at end

Tags: regex, linux, string, sed

I have a last hurdle to solve, but my pattern matching isn't yet up to the task. I have a report and I want to strip out lines with 0 at the end of them... eg.. strip the first line, but leave the second in the output.

For example, given this input:

```
196 Reallocated_Event_Count 0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
199 UDMA_CRC_Error_Count    0x000a   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       22
```

The expected output would be:

```
199 UDMA_CRC_Error_Count    0x000a   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       22
```

I tried various sed combinations such as:

```
sed 's/0$//' file
```

and failed, e.g. the above produced output with just the `0` missing from the end of the line instead of deleting the line.

Comment: I "think" I might have found it... sed -n '/^.* 0$/!p'   maybe?

Comment: that is one way. Test on a larger file. A more traditional way is `grep '[[:space:]]0$' file` alows for a preceding space or tab char (you can use `[[:space:]]` in `sed` too). Good luck.

Comment: `/0$/d` should be enough, yes?  Or `/\b0$/d` if you don't want to delete lines ending in `10`, `20`, `30`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

sed -n '/^.* 0$/!p'

...eventually I got there!

Comment: or less typing: `sed '/ 0$/d'`

Comment: You can accept your own (or anyone else's) answer if it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

Regular expressions aren't always the best solution. Keep in mind [this quote](https://blog.codinghorror.com/regular-expressions-now-you-have-two-problems/):

> Some people, when confronted with a problem, think "I know, I'll use
> regular expressions." Now they have two problems.

Using any awk we can just test if the last field on each line is non-zero and, if so, print that line:

```
$ awk '$NF' file
199 UDMA_CRC_Error_Count    0x000a   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       22
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `grep`:

```
grep -Pv '\s0$' in_file > out_file
```

Here, GNU [`grep`](https://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/grep.html) uses the following options:
`-P` : Use Perl regexes.
`-v` : Print lines that do **not** match.

**See also:**

- [perlre - Perl regular expressions](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre)